# Why does my image not appear on my website

Tags: css, image, debugging, web, css-position

I have been trying to figure this out for sometime now. When I execute my website my images will not upload. As I can see the file on the page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctjuB.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include code as text and not as image.  Please clarify what you mean by 'When I execute my website, my images will not upload".

Comment: please upload your code for better understanding.

Comment: Move your index.html & favicon.ico to the root directory, and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have index.html in the same folder as your images. You can either remove `images/` from your `src='...'` or move all of your images into the images folder and add `images/` to `href='favicon.ico'`.

hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your PNG files are stored in the same directory as the HTML, not inside the `images/` directory (as you probably intended). Try moving the images inside that folder.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS "mountain.png" IF index.html is in the images folder but that is wrong though OR place your index.html out of images folder and add src="./images/mountain.png"